# Changing Redirect to Forward in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two controllers running on different machines, I can redirect the request to second address, however I can't forward it. Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hostname", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hostName(HttpServletRequest request)  {

        String redirectUrl = request.getContextPath() + "http://172.17.0.54:8080/nexthostname?proxyHostName=host2";
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + redirectUrl);
    }
```

So I have 3 hosts in total, 1st host request something from host 3, however host 3 is only accessible through host 2. Therefore, I send the request to host 2 first, so it can get it from host 3 and send it back to host 1. If I do redirect, then host 2 will ask host 1 to directly contact host 3, which is not accessible for host 1.

Any clue that how to forward this request? Should I even forward or send GET request to host 3 through host 2?

Comment: You can't. Forward is performed internally. If you need to go to another machine, it is not internal

Comment: Aha okay, thanks. I updated the question. So should I send GET request to it?

Comment: You should send a GET to host 2 and wait for response. Host 2 should call host 3 and return a response. Instead of redirect, you should call host 2 in your `hostName` method and process the response. Look into `restTemplate` for easy http calls.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.